# C# items check from list of model, and return specific parameter from model

Tags: c#

I am trying to check if any string from `e.ChatMessage.Message` contains any `TrigerWorld(WorldToTrigger)` from model `TrigerWord`. And it should return correct phrase (`FrazeCoSeObjevi`) from TrigerWords. I tried it like this.

Thanks for any answer.

```
List<string> WordInMessage = e.ChatMessage.Message.Split(' ').ToList();

foreach (var item in WordInMessage)
{
    var items = (from x in TrigerWorlds
                 join y in WordInMessage on x.Source equals y
                 select x).ToList():
}
```

There is the model class:

```
namespace FaxSoftware
{
    public class TrigerWorlds
    {
        public string WorldToTriger { get; set; }
        public string FrazeCoSeObjevi { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem? Maybe select x.FrazeCoSeObjevi?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `.Intersect()`?

```cs
var triggerWords = new List<string> {"hello", "world"};
var words = e.ChatMessage.Message.Split(' ').ToList();

var hasTrigger = words.Intersect(triggerWords).Any()
```

This will give you a boolean if there's any trigger word in message.

See documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=netcore-3.1#code-try-2

Answer (score 0):

> According to me there are two ways for doing this.
>
> 1. Instead of using join use .Contains() method of string

```
List<string> WordInMessage = e.ChatMessage.Message.Split(' ').ToList();

 var items = (from x in TrigerWorlds
               where WordInMessage.Contains(x)
                 select x).ToList():
```

> 2. No need to convert e.ChatMessage.Message to list of string.

```
var items = (from x in TrigerWorlds
               where e.ChatMessage.Message.Contains(x)
                 select x).ToList():
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have a collection of TrigerWorlds object and you want a List of those that have matching word in World in Message

You dont need For loop. You can just have this

```
    var items = (from x in triggerCol
                 join y in WordInMessage on x.WorldToTriger equals y
                 select x).ToList();
```